# Would this be considered idiomatic ClojureScript?

Tags: d3.js, clojurescript

I am experimenting/learning ClojureScript. Following code snippet interfaces with the excellent d3.js lib to display some circles. Find it to be bit verbose, without resorting to macros, is there a way to optimize/minimize it?

```
(def rdata (atom (array 3 10 12 16 19)))

(defn update []
(let [em (.selectAll (.select js/d3 "svg") "circle")
     data (.data em @rdata d3/String)
     enter (.append (.enter data) "circle")
     yscale (.linear (. js/d3 -scale))
     xscale (.linear (. js/d3 -scale))
     rscale (.linear (. js/d3 -scale))
     ]
(-> yscale 
  (.domain (array 0 20))
  (.range (array 100 200)))
(-> xscale
  (.domain (array 0 20))
  (.range (array 100 800)))
(-> rscale
  (.domain (array 0 20))
  (.range (array 50 100)))
(-> enter
  (.attr "cx" xscale)
  (.attr "cy" yscale)
  (.attr "r" rscale)
  (.style "fill" "steelblue")
  (.style "stroke" "black")
  (.style "stroke-width" "2")
  )
)
(.info js/console "rdata: " @rdata)
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To initialize the scales you can write `(.linear (.-scale js/d3))`, which is a bit more concise.
Also, in this code snippet there is no reason to use an Atom for the data.
If you want to update the visualization, you could pass new data as an argument to `update` rather than mutating the atom and calling a no-arg update fn.

The threading macro idiomatic for chaining, so you're good there.

Then again, you can't get more idiomatic than using a straight up Clojure library; check out [C2](http://keminglabs.com/c2/), a Clojure(Script) implementation of D3.
(Of course, as the primary author I'm a bit biased on that one.)

If you need to use D3 itself, you might also want to skim the source of the now-deprecated [cljs-d3](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljs-d3) wrapper.

Macros are one way to get a more concise interface (e.g., expanding map literals into multiple `(.attr "key" value)` calls), but the semantics of the chaining macro let you inject any fn into the chain, which is very different from the JavaScript case.
You could, for instance, write a plain fn that takes the d3 selection and an attribute map and uses `doseq` to call `(.attr d3 k v)` for each map key/value.

Actually, there's a [40 minute talk](http://blip.tv/clojure/kevin-lynagh-extending-javascript-libraries-from-clojurescript-5919758) on this exact subject (using D3 as the example) from Clojure Conj last year.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the feedback and heads up on C2 and d3-cljs. C2 looks interesting, i am looking for a purely client side implementation, is it possible to do this with C2/ClojureScript?

Comment: Regarding the Atom for data, want to evolve the code to a dashboard with the data being pushed to the client incrementally... don't know if Atom is the right approach?

Comment: Atom is a great approach for handling state. I'd try to isolate it though: define the atom toplevel but dereference it as little as possible---prefer to pass the data around explicitly via fn arguments.

Comment: Thanks again Kevin, agree with you on isolating the atom. The atom is going to contain a complex hierarchical data structure. The design I am contemplating is to have individual ui components register themselves (using functions as callback) for  data change on the whole or a subset of the data structure. And on data change, a single master function will deref the atom and notify the components and pass the data as args to the callback fn.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a good way to go. When I've run into that scenario in the past I've also stored the primary state in a single atom, then onchange have a watcher to parse out the substates into "derived" atoms, on which you can have watchers for the UI.